# NSMutableArray Allocate then replaceObjectAtIndex

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray that i define in the header file as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tempPhotosArray;
```

Then i allocate as:

```
_tempPhotosArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

What i'd like to know is if i then go to `replaceObjectAtIndex` the program will complain on an out of bounds. I want to keep only a set number of items in that array, so is it possible to do a insert or replace? i.e. if at index 0 it is empty do an insert, if there is an object already replace it?

Thanks

Comment: If you know the number of items in the array then after allocation the array you can fill it with NSNull objects as many as the items you will replace. After that you can simply replaceObjectAtIndex without problem ... You can also change the array and make it dictionary ... It really depends on what you are trying to do

Comment: Hi - thanks. i see that method however the array changes. Maybe a dictionary could be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

i think i agree with Hani Ibrahim. Since you said you only want to keep a set number of objects in the array. So how many you want?

```
   // add these code when you initialize the array
   int aSetNumber = 5;

   _tempPhotosArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   for (int i = 0; i < aSetNumber; i++)
   {
      [_tempPhotosArray addobject: [NSNull null]];
   }
```

i guess then you can do whatever you want, i don't know what exactly you want to do in this case, but i would check if the object in that position is NSNUll, if so, replace that, if not, i don't know what you want them

```
   //use these code when you trying to insert the real object
   if([[_tempPhotoArray objectAtIndex:anIndex] isKindOfClass: [NSNull class]])
   {
        //replace it here
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

As to why you are getting an error, what everyone else wrote is accurate, but....

The description of what you want doesn't match what an `NSArray` is. It sounds like you want a list of up to 5 items and never more than 5. It might be that if you try to add a 6th item the "oldest" goes away. Like a "recently opened" file history. You can make this type of functionality with an `NSArray`, but that's not what it is out of the box.

I would suggest making your own object class. I'm not going to write all the code for you, because this sounds suspiciously like programming homework, but I will point you in the correct direction.

`FivePack`  <-- our class
`NSArray *storage;` <-- where we house the data

```
// a public method which lets you add things.
- (void)addItem:(id)item {
    int indexOfLastItemInArrayToSave = 4;
    if (storage.length < 4)
        indexOfLastItemInArrayToSave = length-1;

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, indexOfLastItemInArrayToSave);
    NSArray *temp = [storage subArrayWithRange:range];

    // now create a new array with the first item being "item" that 
    // was passed in and the rest of the array being the contents of temp.
    // Then save that to storage.
}
```

What you want to do with the data and writing something to get it from your new object is up to you, because I'm not sure how you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no objects in the array when you initially created it, so there is nothing to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
if([_tempPhotosArray  count] > 0)
    //replace object
else
    //add object to array
```